# Projeto flyway e jpa-hibernate se confudindo

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

No projeto que estamos criando, em local, ao inicial o **JPA - hibernate**, criava as tabelas e inseria algumas informações, para testes.

Bom o projeto foi crescendo e decidimos incluir o **flyway** para versionamento de tabelas, já que vimos que este projeto faz isso.

Antes de colocarmos o **flyway** , o **application_core.properties** era assim:

> ```
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/usuarios
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
> spring.datasource.username=postgres
> spring.datasource.password=
>
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
> spring.data.rest.base-path=/usuarios/api
> server.port=8090
>
> spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
> spring.jpa.show-sql=true
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=false
> spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_schema=event_log
>
> logging.level.root=INFO
> logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO
> logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
> ```

Isto é, ao iniciar o servidor, ele automaticamente criava as **table**, **index**, **constraint** no banco de dados.

agora é assim:

> ```
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/usuarios
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
> spring.datasource.username=postgres
> spring.datasource.password=
>
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
> spring.data.rest.base-path=/usuarios/api
> server.port=8090
>
> spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
> spring.jpa.show-sql=true
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=false
> spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_schema=event_log
>
> logging.level.root=INFO
> logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO
> logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
> ```

Isto é, a propriedade **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto** era **create** e passou a ser **none**.

Só que mesmo passando a **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto** para **none**, o **JPA - hibernate** está criando as tabelas, automaticamente.

O projeto está divido em módulos **core**, **rest**, **util** e **flyway**.

Em cada módulo tem uma configuração:

Módulo **flyway**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EntityScan(ConfiguracaoFlyway.PACOTE)
@ComponentScan({ ConfiguracaoFlyway.PACOTE })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = ConfiguracaoFlyway.PACOTE)
@PropertySource("classpath:application_flyway.properties")
public class ConfiguracaoFlyway {
    static final String PACOTE = "br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.flyway";
}
```

Módulo **core**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EntityScan(ConfiguracaoCore.PACOTE)
@ComponentScan({ ConfiguracaoCore.PACOTE })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = ConfiguracaoCore.PACOTE)
@PropertySource("classpath:application_core.properties")
public class ConfiguracaoCore {
    static final String PACOTE = "br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core";
}
```

O **application_flyway.properties** está assim:

> ```
> flyway.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
> flyway.urll=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/usuarios
> flyway.user=postgres
> flyway.password=
> flyway.schemas=public
> ```

O que pode ser ?

Comment: Já experimentou remover totalmente a propriedade `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` do arquivo?

Comment: Vou testar e informo aqui

Comment: Tenta remover essa propriedade tbm `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true`