# Erro após utilzar Flyway no projeto

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, flyway

Conforme falei neste tópico [Projeto flyway e jpa-hibernate se confudindo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/438337/projeto-flyway-e-jpa-hibernate-se-confudindo), inclui no nosso projeto o Flyway,

Após fazer funcionar corretamente o Flyway e o projeto criar as tabelas, fazer inserção, alteração e exclusão no sql.

Quando o Spring inicia, dá o erro abaixo. Só que antes não acontecia este erro, informado abaixo.

O que pode ser ?

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-07 10:46:18.868 ERROR 14028 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaUsuarioRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'incluisao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaUsuarioInclusaoController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pessoaUsuarioService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaUsuarioServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaUsuarioRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.PessoaUsuario br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.impl.PessoaUsuarioRepository.findByByPessoaAndUsuario(br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.Pessoa,br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.usuario.Usuario)! No property byPessoa found for type PessoaUsuario!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.UsuariosApplication.main(UsuariosApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaUsuarioInclusaoController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pessoaUsuarioService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaUsuarioServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaUsuarioRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.PessoaUsuario br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.impl.PessoaUsuarioRepository.findByByPessoaAndUsuario(br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.Pessoa,br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.usuario.Usuario)! No property byPessoa found for type PessoaUsuario!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pessoaUsuarioService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaUsuarioServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaUsuarioRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.PessoaUsuario br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.impl.PessoaUsuarioRepository.findByByPessoaAndUsuario(br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.Pessoa,br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.usuario.Usuario)! No property byPessoa found for type PessoaUsuario!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaUsuarioServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaUsuarioRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.PessoaUsuario br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.impl.PessoaUsuarioRepository.findByByPessoaAndUsuario(br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.Pessoa,br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.usuario.Usuario)! No property byPessoa found for type PessoaUsuario!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pessoaUsuarioRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.PessoaUsuario br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.impl.PessoaUsuarioRepository.findByByPessoaAndUsuario(br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.Pessoa,br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.usuario.Usuario)! No property byPessoa found for type PessoaUsuario!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.PessoaUsuario br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.impl.PessoaUsuarioRepository.findByByPessoaAndUsuario(br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.Pessoa,br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.usuario.Usuario)! No property byPessoa found for type PessoaUsuario!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:84) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:566) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:561) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property byPessoa found for type PessoaUsuario!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    ... 94 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Difícil olhando somente  o log, verifica se seu bean validation está utilizando os imports corretos no caso javax.persistence.* para detalhar melhor coloque suas migrações, o resource em questão. services e entidades.

Comment: @AndréMartins coloquei os códigos. na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

**PessoaUsuarioRestController**

```
package br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.rest.pessoausuario;

import br.com.ghsistemas.principal.utilitario.mensagem.Mensagem;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.exception.PessoaException;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.resource.PessoaEnvioResource;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.resource.PessoaFiltroResource;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.resource.PessoaPaginacaoResource;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.resource.PessoaRetornoResource;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.usuario.resource.UsuarioAlterarSenhaEnvioResource;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.usuario.resource.UsuarioAlterarSenhaRetornoResource;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.rest.UsuariosController;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.rest.pessoausuario.controller.PessoaUsuarioInclusaoController;
import lombok.extern.apachecommons.CommonsLog;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Collection;

import static br.com.ghsistemas.principal.utilitario.constantes.ConstantesUtil.*;
import static br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.utilitario.constantes.Constantes.*;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE;

@CommonsLog
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/pessoasUsuarios")
public class PessoaUsuarioRestController extends UsuariosController {

    @Autowired
    private PessoaUsuarioInclusaoController incluisao;

    @PostMapping(value = "/incluir", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(code = CREATED)
    //@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR)")
    public ResponseEntity<?> incluir(@RequestBody PessoaEnvioResource resource) throws PessoaException {
        try {
            resource.setLoginUsuario(retornLoginContexto().getUsername());
            PessoaRetornoResource incluir = incluisao.incluir(resource);
            incluir.setMensagens(mensagemSalvar(false));
            return new ResponseEntity<>(incluir, OK);
        } catch (PessoaException e) {
            return excecaoPessoaUsuario(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return excecaoGeral(e, ERRO_PESSOA_USUARIO_CHAVE + INCLUIR_CHAVE,
                    ERRO_EM + INCLUIR + PESSOA_USUARIO + EXCLAMACAO);
        }
    }

    private PessoaEnvioResource preencherResource(String id) {
        PessoaEnvioResource resource = PessoaEnvioResource.builder().build();
        resource.setLoginUsuario(retornLoginContexto().getUsername());
        resource.setId(id);
        return resource;
    }

    private ResponseEntity<?> excecaoPessoaUsuario(PessoaException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        Collection<Mensagem> mensagems = mensagemSalvar(true);
        mensagems.addAll(e.getMensagens());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(mensagems, CONFLICT);
    }
}
```

**PessoaUsuarioInclusaoController**

```
package br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.rest.pessoausuario.controller;

import br.com.ghsistemas.principal.utilitario.mensagem.Mensagem;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.exception.PessoaException;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.PessoaService;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.resource.PessoaEnvioResource;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.resource.PessoaRetornoResource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

@Component
public class PessoaUsuarioInclusaoController {

    @Autowired
    private PessoaService service;

    public PessoaRetornoResource incluir(PessoaEnvioResource pessoaEnvioResource) throws PessoaException {
        Collection<Mensagem> mensagens = new ArrayList<>();
        return service.incluir(pessoaEnvioResource, mensagens);
    }
}
```

**PessoaService**

```
package br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario;

import java.util.Collection;

import br.com.ghsistemas.principal.utilitario.mensagem.Mensagem;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.resource.PessoaUsuarioResource;

public interface PessoaUsuarioService {

    void incluir(PessoaUsuarioResource resource, Collection<Mensagem> mensagens);
}
```

**PessoaUsuarioServiceImpl**

```
import static br.com.ghsistemas.principal.core.enuns.StatusDoRegistroEnum.EXCLUIDO;
import static br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.utilitario.constantes.Constantes.ERRO_PESSOA_USUARIO_CHAVE;
import static br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.utilitario.constantes.Constantes.PESSOA_USUARIO_MAIUSCULO;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import br.com.ghsistemas.principal.core.regras.ValidarIncluirAlterarExcluir;
import br.com.ghsistemas.principal.utilitario.mensagem.Mensagem;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.PessoaUsuario;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.PessoaUsuarioService;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.impl.regras.alterar.PessoaUsuarioRegraAlterar;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.impl.regras.incluir.PessoaUsuarioRegraIncluir;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.resource.PessoaUsuarioResource;

@Service
public class PessoaUsuarioServiceImpl extends PessoaUsuarioImpl implements PessoaUsuarioService {

    @Autowired
    private PessoaUsuarioRegraIncluir regraIncluir;
    @Autowired
    private ValidarIncluirAlterarExcluir validacaoId;

    @Override
    public void incluir(PessoaUsuarioResource resource, Collection<Mensagem> mensagens) {
        validacaoId.validarIncluir(resource.getId(), mensagens);
        validarMensagem(mensagens);
        regraIncluir.validarIncluir(resource, mensagens);
        validarMensagem(mensagens);
    }
}
```

**PessoaUsuarioRepository**

```
package br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.impl;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoa.Pessoa;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.pessoausuario.PessoaUsuario;
import br.com.ghsistemas.usuarios.core.usuario.Usuario;

@Repository
interface PessoaUsuarioRepository extends CrudRepository<PessoaUsuario, String> {

    PessoaUsuario findByByPessoaAndUsuario(Pessoa pessoa, Usuario usuario);
}
```